# How I can start and stop applications deployed in a tomcat embedded server

Tags: java, embedded-tomcat-7

I have a tomcat embedded server to test my web applications and I would like to be able to start and stop applications that are already deployed, how can I do that?

Comment: How you deploy it?

Comment: I created a folder and I put in my wars files and in my code.
`tomcat.getHost (). setAutoDeploy (true);`

Answer (score 0):

You deploy the [Manager App](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html) too, and use it to:

- [Upload and Deploy WAR file](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Archive_(WAR)_Remotely)
- [Deploy local Directory or WAR file](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_from_a_Local_Path)
- [Start Application](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Start_an_Existing_Application)
- [Stop Application](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Stop_an_Existing_Application)
- [Undeploy Application](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Undeploy_an_Existing_Application)
- ...

Alternatively, to just Start and Stop an Application, you can use [JMX](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/monitoring.html), and invoke the `start` and `stop` methods on e.g. `Catalina:type=Manager,context=/servlets-examples,host=localhost`.